# Remotely enable or disable Administrative Share

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is it possible to enable or disable a Windows "Administrative Share" (e.g ipc$, admin$, c$, d$), remotely?

Comment: Only if the remote registry service is running on the remote machine. I think Home Basic doesn't have that at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can remotely run commands on a machine using [Psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).

To disable  the IPC$ share, the command would look something like:

`psexec \\computername -u administrator -p password net share ipc$ /delete`

If you need to modify the registry in this case, you could replace the `net share` command at the end with the necessary `regedit` command:

`psexec \\computername -u administrator -p password regedit /parameters`

Comment: In order for PSEXEC to work, IPC$ needs to be enabled, so this solution won't work.

Comment: The user is asking how to **disable** it, which implies it is enabled, so yes, it will work.

Comment: The title says 'enable'. Only in the description does he add 'disable'. Agree 100% for using your solution to disable, but he also asked how to enable. Not trying to throw water just looking at entire request. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, and if you could you would break things that need named pipes. For example, domain controllers communicating Group Policy to workstations.

But you can get rid of the driveletter$ and admin$.
XP: Adding a DWORD value of AutoShareWks with a value of 0 (zero) to MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters

Win7+ (off by default, but you can make sure)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy"=dword:00000000

For 64-bit machines it would bw a qword.

One other thing, looking at the 1st answer above, the use of psexec isn't necessary to do this or not. You can connect to remote registry and do it if you want to do machine by machine, but most people would use group policy.

Comment: Hi jamie! We're not a forum. Please [edit] your posts to add info, rather than posting multiple answers to the same question. Thanks! You should also register your account in case you lose your login cookie.